# How to get the exsiting mapping in an ElasticSearch index

Tags: c#, .net, elasticsearch, nest

Using Nest and C# I would like to examine the mapping present in an index.

```
var settings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
var status = client.Status();
```

This will return the available indices of the ES server. But I would also like to know what types are mapped in those indices. 
I tried using:

```
var mapping = client.GetMapping(???);
```

But these methods and overloads seem to need the name of the mapping. Which is exactly what I am trying to find out. I cannot find the proper documentation for this situation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use either overload to pull down the mapping for a specific index/type (but *currently* not plural indices or types)

```
client.GetMapping(g => g.Index("myindex").Type("mytype")));
```

versus

```
client.GetMapping(new GetMappingRequest {Index = "myindex", Type = "mytype"});
```

I cannot be sure what will happen when you implicitly supply `<object>` (it may explode; I'm not on a Windows machine to test it), but you obviously do not *know* the type (`T`) to put there and need something.

Unfortunately, the current limitation with the above (assuming it works with `<object>`) is that you must supply an `Index`, and optionally its `Type`. If you do not specify the `Type`, but the `Index` contains more than one type, then it will just pick the first one that gets returned. And I doubt that is what you want, which is why [I created an issue for it on GitHub](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/issues/1066) after discussing it with Greg (one of the NEST developers).

Fortunately, there is always a fallback in NEST, which is to go to the lower level Elasticsearch.NET APIs. There you can make your `IndicesGetMapping` request. Reviewing the [generated tests can be found here](https://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/blob/develop/src/Tests/Elasticsearch.Net.Integration.Yaml/indices.get_mapping/10_basic.yaml.cs), which will probably help to understand it better for the generated request.

```
var response = client.IndicesGetMapping("test_1,test_2");

// Deserialized JSON:
//
// response.test_1.mappings.type_1.properties
// response.test_1.mappings.type_2.properties
// response.test_2.mappings.type_a.properties
```

Note, could also use these overloads too:

```
// First parameter is indices (comma separated, potentially wildcarded list)
// _all is a special placeholder to [shockingly] specify all
var response = client.IndicesGetMapping("_all", "_all");
var response = client.IndicesGetMapping("index1,index2", "_all");
// Enjoy the loops:
var response = client.IndicesGetMappingForAll();
```

These can be [found in `IElasticsearchClient.Generated`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch-net/develop/src/Elasticsearch.Net/IElasticsearchClient.Generated.cs) (huge file, so search for "`IndicesGetMapping`").

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was indeed hoping for a higher level of being able to retrieve the meta-data. I will keep an eye on the outcome of the Github issue. For now I will use the low level implementation.

Comment: @FrankWite FYI you can access the low-level client through NEST via the `Raw` property:  `client.Raw.IndicesGetMapping(...)`.

Answer (score 0):

This post is old .. I am sharing the solution which worked for me in Elasticsearch Nest 5.0. I have only one index and getting the mapping like this

```
var mapping = client.GetMapping(new GetMappingRequest()).Mappings.AsEnumerable().FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Hope can help others.